# About DRM flow, how to pass message to provisioning server?

Tags: cobalt

In starboard DRM API (src/starboard/drm.h), there seems no flow to handle Widevine device certificate request with provisioning server?

In my starboard DRM module, should I perform "HTTP POST" directly to provisioning server?

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Starboard DRM is intended to implement the [Encrypted Media Extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/encrypted-media/) (EME). With EME,  the web application requests a license from the [Content Decryption Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/encrypted-media/#definitions) (CDM) and sends it to the server. It then passes the response back down into the CDM. In this case, the SbDrm implementation represents the CDM.

So, the SbDrm implementation should not make any network requests to the license server. The web app should make those requests on behalf of the CDM.

Comment: In the document [Widevine Level 1 Provisioning Models](https://storage.googleapis.com/wvdocs/Widevine_DRM_Device_Provisioning_Models.pdf), how Provisioning 2.0 and 3.0 can be done by current interface? License request and reply with license server has no problem, the problem is, how to request and reply with provisioning server?

Comment: Ah, I see. You can do your own HTTP post, but it is preferred to report the provisioning request as the first licensing request, and the app will send the HTTP POST for you. You can then send the real license request as an unsolicited license request once the provisioning response has been received.